Calculate average open days of tickets grouped per / over month(s)
I have the following (simplified) table (Oracle DB):



id
created_at
solved_at




1
2023-10-15
2023-10-29


2
2023-10-20



3
2023-11-01
2023-12-02


4
2023-11-15
2023-11-20


5
2023-12-03
2024-01-10


6
2024-01-04
2024-01-10



I want to calculate the number of days tickets were / are open per month. The important part is that an open ticket will be included in the calculation in every month in which it is open.
From the example above, it would be:
2023-10: 4 days from ticket 1 (solved_at - created_at) and 11 days from ticket2 (because it record was open / not solved the whole month). So average open days is (4 + 12) / 2 = 8
2023-11: 30 days from ticket2 (because it is still open) + 30 days from ticket 3 (also open the whole month) + 5 days from ticket 4. Avg open days is 65 / 3 = 21,6 days.
I'm not new to SQL, but I never faced something like that. Theoretically, it is possible to just Select the months I want from a temp table / hard coded and join the records but isn't there a better solution for this?

I'd start by creating a (temporary or CTE) table that holds a row for each month you are interested in - with the start and end dates for each month. Then LEFT JOIN your table to this and you should be able to build your query quite easily

Generate a calendar and then outer join to the calendar and take the average of the days within that month:
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(min_dt, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   (
    SELECT MIN(created_at) AS min_dt,
           MAX(COALESCE(solved_at, SYSDATE)) AS max_dt
    FROM   table_name
  )
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(min_dt, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1) <= max_dt
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(c.month, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
       AVG(
         LEAST(COALESCE(t.solved_at, TRUNC(SYSDATE)), ADD_MONTHS(c.month, 1))
         - GREATEST(t.created_at, c.month)
       ) AS avg_days
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       ON (c.month < COALESCE(t.solved_at, SYSDATE)
           AND t.created_at < ADD_MONTHS(c.month, 1))
GROUP BY
       c.month

Which, for the sample data:
create table table_name (id, created_at, solved_at) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-10-15', DATE '2023-10-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-10-20', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-11-01', DATE '2023-12-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2023-11-15', DATE '2023-11-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2023-12-03', DATE '2024-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, DATE '2024-01-04', DATE '2024-01-10' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



MONTH
AVG_DAYS




2023-10
13


2023-11
21.66666666666666666666666666666666666667


2023-12
20.33333333333333333333333333333333333333


2024-01
15.33333333333333333333333333333333333333


2024-02
29


2024-03
31


2024-04
14



fiddle

One of the options is to create a CTE (grid) with all the months of interest. Join it to your table data and define start and end of each month and  solved_at date for your IDs that has null as solved_at (otherwise it lasts forever). The resultset of the grid cte should let you calculate the days opened values to get the averages.
There are a few assumptions here - first I took the months from your created_at column which could have some gaps that should be filled. The same goes for possible extended months in your solved_at column at the end. Second, I took them both as opened period the created_at and the solved_at columns (+1 day at substruction) you should adjust it if the assumption is wrong.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( ID, CREATED_AT, SOLVED_AT ) AS
        ( Select 1, DATE '2023-10-15', DATE '2023-10-29'  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, DATE '2023-10-20', Null               From Dual Union All
          Select 3, DATE '2023-11-01', DATE '2023-12-02'  From Dual Union All
          Select 4, DATE '2023-11-15', DATE '2023-11-20'  From Dual Union All
          Select 5, DATE '2023-12-03', DATE '2024-01-10'  From Dual Union All
          Select 6, DATE '2024-01-04', DATE '2024-01-10'  From Dual 
        ),

  grid AS
    ( Select    m.MONTH_ID,  
                t.*,
                LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(m.MONTH_ID, 'yyyy-mm'), -1) ) + 1 "START_MONTH",
                LAST_DAY(To_Date(m.MONTH_ID, 'yyyy-mm')) "END_MONTH", 
                LEAST(t.SOLVED_AT, LAST_DAY(To_Date(m.MONTH_ID, 'yyyy-mm'))) - 
                GREATEST(t.CREATED_AT, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(m.MONTH_ID, 'yyyy-mm'), -1) ) + 1) + 1 "DAYS",
                Count(Distinct t.ID) Over(Partition By m.MONTH_ID) "CNT"
      From    ( Select  Distinct 
                        To_Char(CREATED_AT, 'yyyy-mm') "MONTH_ID"
                From      tbl
              ) m
      Left Join ( Select  ID, CREATED_AT, Nvl(SOLVED_AT, Max(SOLVED_AT) Over()) "SOLVED_AT"
                  From    tbl
                ) t ON(m.MONTH_ID Between To_Char(t.CREATED_AT, 'yyyy-mm') And To_Char(t.SOLVED_AT, 'yyyy-mm'))
      Order By  m.MONTH_ID, t.ID
    )

/*    R e s u l t :    (grid)
MONTH_ID         ID CREATED_AT SOLVED_AT START_MONTH END_MONTH       DAYS        CNT
-------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------- --------- ---------- ----------
2023-10           1 15.10.23   29.10.23  01.10.23    31.10.23          15          2
2023-10           2 20.10.23   10.01.24  01.10.23    31.10.23          12          2
2023-11           2 20.10.23   10.01.24  01.11.23    30.11.23          30          3
2023-11           3 01.11.23   02.12.23  01.11.23    30.11.23          30          3
2023-11           4 15.11.23   20.11.23  01.11.23    30.11.23           6          3
2023-12           2 20.10.23   10.01.24  01.12.23    31.12.23          31          3
2023-12           3 01.11.23   02.12.23  01.12.23    31.12.23           2          3
2023-12           5 03.12.23   10.01.24  01.12.23    31.12.23          29          3
2024-01           2 20.10.23   10.01.24  01.01.24    31.01.24          10          3
2024-01           5 03.12.23   10.01.24  01.01.24    31.01.24          10          3
2024-01           6 04.01.24   10.01.24  01.01.24    31.01.24           7          3    */

NOTE: Columns ID, CREATED_AT, SOLVED_AT (t.*), START_MONTH and END_MONTH in the above resutset are not needed - they are here just for clarification purposes.
-- M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    MONTH_ID, 
          Round(Sum(DAYS) / Max(CNT), 2) "AVG_DAYS_OPENED"
FROM      grid 
GROUP BY  MONTH_ID
ORDER BY  MONTH_ID

/*    R e s u l t :
MONTH_ID AVG_DAYS_OPENED
-------- ---------------
2023-10             13,5
2023-11               22
2023-12            20,67
2024-01                9 */

